# How to include ros msg outside of ros environment?

Tags: ros

I am utilizing ros outside of the ros workspace using g++ and i want to include a custom msg I made. Normally I would just do "#include "msg_filter/my_msg.h"" but that doesn't seem to work outside the environment. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's get into the low-level of what's happening. If you have a `catkin_ws/src/my_pkg/msg/CustomMessage.msg`, and you compile it correctly (you can use it as normal within ROS), you'll find a header file for it at `catkin_ws/devel/include/my_pkg/CustomMessage.h` and a python msg file at `catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/my_pkg/msg/_MyMsg.py`. You can still see them, in another workspace, if you have `source catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`, either at the cmd line or in your .bashrc.

But trying to compile & utilize ROS msgs outside of the catkin buildsystem is probably unwise - at that point it's far easier to make your own data struct in a common header & use that for interfacing between libraries or programs (just guessing at your use case).
For the record, while you could compile ROS related things on the cmd line using g++ (the rest of the headers/libs are at `/opt/ros/<distro>/`), I suspect that would be more quickly painful than changing your dependencies/interfaces or doing it within catkin.

Answer (score 0):

A very dirty way is to do a trap on the IP traffic.